# Question on CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have a selector like

```
#myTable tr td .someClass{....}
```

Does this someClass refer "ONLY" to td having that class OR does it refer to any child of td having "someClass" ? So Is it same as ;

```
#myTable tr td.someClass{....}
```

Basically my question is does the space after td make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the space makes a difference:

```
td.someClass {...} //Refers to a table cell with the class someClass
td .someClass {...} //Refers to an element with the class someClass that is a descendant of a table cell
```

Answer (score 3):

`#myTable tr td .someClass{....}` refers to **any element** with a class of `someClass` **that is inside** a `td` tag, that is inside a `tr` tag, that is inside an element with an id of `myTable`.

`#myTable tr td.someClass{....}` refers to a `td` tag **with** a class of `someClass`, that is inside a `tr` tag, that is inside an element with an id of `myTable`.

Answer (score 1):

The former selector refers to an element of class `someClass` that's a descendant of a `td`.

To refer to a `td` element of class-name `someClass` use the latter selector.

The space is a descendent selector; if you want an immediate child (no elements between the `td` and the `.someClass` element) use `>`:

```
#myTable tr td > .someClass{....}
```

Answer (score 0):

A space separate children from parent. Without the space you are telling the CSS to find an element with that class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

- first case targets an child element of your td, having class "someclass"
- second case targets td having class "someclass"

Answer (score 0):

The space does make a difference. The first selector selects any element with the class `someClass` that is a child of a `td` in a `tr` in `myTable`.

The second selects any `td` with the class `someClass` that is a child of a `tr` in `myTable`

Answer (score 0):

The space after the `td`does make a difference

css:

```
#myTable tr td.someClass{ color:brown; }
#myTable tr td .someClass{ color:red; }
```

html:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td class="someClass">
        cofee
        <span class="someClass">
            wine
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

cofee will appear brown, and wine red.